# Stash & Low Search - Group results by releationship

Tags: stash, search, low-search

I'm trying to group the results returned from Low Search using Stash. I started by creating a stash list of all the groups, I then tried to create a nested list containing the products for that group.

When I call the get_list, I can return the groups just fine, but trying to fetch the products returns nothing.

Here is my code so far (Bear in mind I know that this will add ALL products into each group, but I'm taking this one step at a time)

```
{layout="includes/_layout"}

    {exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}

        {!-- Set Other Page Data --}


        {!-- Results --}
        {exp:stash:set_list:searchRanges name="searchRanges" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
            {exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" collection="products" keywords:lang="en" keywords:inflect="yes" keywords:loose="right" keywords:mode="all" limit="999"}
                {stash:itemRange}{products__range:url_title}{/stash:itemRange}

                {exp:stash:append_list:nested name="searchResults--{products__range:url_title}" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
                    {stash:productTitle}sdfds{/stash:productTitle}
                {/exp:stash:append_list:nested}
            {/exp:low_search:results}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:searchRanges}

    {/exp:stash:set}



    {!-- Fetch the data --}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="searchRanges" unique="itemRange"}
        <p>{itemRange} - This is being returned.</p>

        {!-- Adding process="end" to this makes it return the correct amount, but adding process="end" to the nested get_list still returns nothing --}
        {exp:stash:list_count name="searchResults--{itemRange}" process="end"}

        {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="searchResults--{itemRange}"}
            <p>This content isn't being returned</p>
        {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
```

**Edit**

Looking at the template debugger, I can see the get_list is parsing the `name="searchResults--{itemRange}"` correctly, but I can't see the list being set anywhere, so looks like an it's an issue with the nested list not being set. I've tried adding process="end" to the nested append_list but nothing still

Comment: The closing tag for the nested stash append tag has a typo in it. It should be: `{/exp:stash:append_list:nested}`.

Comment: I did notice that, sorry forget to update the code, didn't make a difference though.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a Low Search issue/question, as the same can be replicated with the native channel:entries tag. And I'm not a Stash expert, so I'm afraid I can't chip in on that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one list. You can use the `unique=""` parameter to output unique values of a given column, and the `match=""` & `against=""` parameters in a nested call to the same list to select products that match each unique value.

```
{!-- Capture search results --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="products" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
    {exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" collection="products" keywords:lang="en" keywords:inflect="yes" keywords:loose="right" keywords:mode="all" limit="999"}
        {stash:item_range}{products__range:url_title}{/stash:item_range}
        {stash:product_title}{title}{/stash:product_title}
    {/exp:low_search:results}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- Output products grouped by range --}
{exp:stash:get_list name="products" unique="item_range" orderby="item_range" sort="asc"}

    <h1>Range: {item_range}</h1>

    <ul>
    {exp:stash:get_list:range name="products" match="#^{item_range}$#" against="item_range" prefix="range"}
        <li>{range:product_title}</li>
    {/exp:stash:get_list:range}
    </ul>

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Really close, `product_title` is repeating the same value

Comment: Using a `prefix` on the inner get_list fixed the issue, cheers!

Comment: Ah yes sorry forgot that - edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

See Mark's answer, it's much better.

---

I managed to sort the issue myself, I'm sure there is a better way of doing this, but it works for now.

### Setting

I first started by getting all the product ranges into a list. Notice the `parse_depth="2"` on the outer set tag. This does not work without it.

```
{exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" parse_depth="2"}

    {!-- Get all product ranges --}
    {exp:stash:set_list:productRanges name="productRanges" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="ranges" dynamic="no" limit="999" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
            {stash:rangeName}{title}{/stash:rangeName}
            {stash:rangeShortname}{url_title}{/stash:rangeShortname}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:productRanges}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

Now that we've got the ranges stored, we can then create a new list per range, and then using the `match` and `against` parameters, we can add products from the search results to each list if they are assigned to that product range.

```
{exp:stash:set parse_conditionals="yes" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" parse_depth="2"}

    {!-- Get all product ranges --}
    {exp:stash:set_list:productRanges name="productRanges" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="ranges" dynamic="no" limit="999" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
            {stash:rangeName}{title}{/stash:rangeName}
            {stash:rangeShortname}{url_title}{/stash:rangeShortname}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list:productRanges}

    {!-- Create a new list for each range, and add the products from the search results if they are assigned to that range. --}
    {exp:stash:get_list name="productRanges"}
        {exp:stash:set_list:rangeProducts name="results--{rangeShortname}" parse_tags="yes" trim="yes" match="#{rangeShortname}#" against="productRange"}
            {exp:low_search:results query="{segment_3}" collection="products" keywords:lang="en" keywords:inflect="yes" keywords:loose="right" keywords:mode="all" limit="999"}
                {stash:productName}{title}{/stash:productName}
                {stash:productRange}{products__range:url_title}{/stash:productRange}
            {/exp:low_search:results}
        {/exp:stash:set_list:rangeProducts}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

### Getting

Now that the lists are set it's easy to get them.

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="productRanges"}
    {if {exp:stash:not_empty name="results--{rangeShortname}"}}
        <p>{rangeShortname}</p>

        <ul>
            {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="results--{rangeShortname}"}
               <li>{productName}</li>
            {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
        </ul>
    {/if}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```